# JSON data is converting to encoded URL

Tags: json, rest, api

I am want to send JSON object in url directly. something like

```
https://example.com/api/{"node1":[{"id":"32","Title":"000w","type":"Final"}]}
```

but when I create request it convert this url to

```
https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fapi%2F%7B%22node1%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%2232%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22000w%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Final%22%7D%5D%7D
```

I don't want to pass like that I want to hit server in first manner.

Comment: How are you creating the request?

Comment: @theGleep i am creating like this, options = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); this.http.get(this.singleton.apiUrl + "create/" + JSON.stringify(createData), options)

Comment: The thing that really sticks out to me (and might be completely unrelated to your question) is that you have "https%3a%2f%2f..." instead of "https://..." - I don't know if I've ever tried hitting a site with anything before the query string encoded.  Maybe if you trace back to where that is being encoded, you could figure out how your JSON is getting encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stringify and encode it if you *really* want to send a lump of JSON in a URL:

```
var yourObject = {"node1":[{"id":"32","Title":"000w","type":"Final"}]};
var encoded = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(yourObject));

console.log(encoded);
```

gives:

```
"eyJub2RlMSI6W3siaWQiOiIzMiIsIlRpdGxlIjoiMDAwdyIsInR5cGUiOiJGaW5hbCJ9XX0="
```

To get your object back at the other end, you can do:

```
JSON.parse(atob("eyJub2RlMSI6W3siaWQiOiIzMiIsIlRpdGxlIjoiMDAwdyIsInR5cGUiOiJGaW5hbCJ9XX0="))
```

OR

To decode what you end up with in your question, use `decodeURIComponent`:

```
var theString = 'https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2F%7B%22node1%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%2232%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22000w%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Final%22%7D%5D%7D';
decodeURIComponent(theString);
```

gives you back:

```
https://example.com/api/{"node1":[{"id":"32","Title":"000w","type":"Final"}]}
```

Comment: is there any other way ?because api is already hosted and this can't be edited.

Comment: You could simply `decodeURIComponent()` it. I'll add that to my answer....